# Writing a dataframe to a SQL database without replacing table format

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure Databricks and pyspark to process data using dataframes and I use Azure SQL Database to store the data after it's been processed. I have created the output tables using ordinary CREATE TABLE scripts in SQL, but I realized that the dataframe write method overwrites the table format. E.g. all the string columns become nvarchar(max). Is there any way to keep the table format as specified in the CREATE TABLE script?

Example of my write statement in pyspark:

```
df.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net;databaseName=mydatabase;")
  .option("dbtable", "mytable")
  .option("user", jdbcUsername)
  .option("password", jdbcPassword)
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .save()
```

Comment: Change the mode to `append` instead of `overwrite`. See here: [Save modes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#save-modes)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to replace the data already in the table. If I'm using append, is there some way to truncate the table first?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the schema using [customSchema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

Below is an example:

```
df.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net;databaseName=mydatabase;")
  .option("dbtable", "mytable")
  .option("user", jdbcUsername)
  .option("password", jdbcPassword)
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .option("customSchema", "your_str_col_here STRING")
  .save()
```